# Difference of two exponential terms

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

While learning some stochastics, I stumbled upon two  similar estimations I can`t understand.

1. $|e^{-it(x+h)}-e^{-itx}|\leq |h|$
2. $|\frac{e^{-it(a)}-e^{-itb}}{it}e^{itx}| \leq |b-a|$

All it says is, that these are a direct consequence of the taylor series, but I don't get it.

Could it also be a consequence of the fact, that the exponential function is convex?

Comment: In (1.) Shouldn't the second exp also have an $x$, that is $e^{-itx}$?

Comment: oh you`re right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that in your inequalities, all $t,x,h,a,b$ are real numbers. You could derive the two inequalities as follows. For any real numbers $p$ and $q$;
$$
|e^{iq}-e^{ip}|=\left|-ie^{it}|_p^q\right|=|\int_{p}^qe^{it}\;dt| \leq \int_{p}^q|e^{it}|\;dt=q-p
$$

To get (1), consider $p=-t(x+h)$ and $q=-tx$.
To get (2), let $p=-ta$ and $q=-tb$.

Comment: thanks! That´s a nice and easy solution

Comment: @wcmynb: you are welcome